# Gong Drag&Drop: Subscribe to drop event

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I fear, this is something obvious I'm overlooking, but I'm a bit stuck:

I'm using Gong Solution Drag&Drop library for drag&drop from one view to another. I have written a custom drop handler, which handles my data transfer as well as updating the data on source and target (`ListView` in this case).

Now I want my ViewModel class corresponding to the source view to subscribe to the drop event in the target view. However, I can't find the drop event exposed by the gong library. My next thought was to write my own event within my custom drag or drop handler, however this classes are completely decoupled from the source ViewModel, so how would I subscribe to the event?

A bit of code (relevant parts):

**Target Grid:**

```
<Grid dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{StaticResource CustomDropHandler}">
<!-- Stuff in my view -->
</Grid>
```

**Custom Drag Handler** (doesn't do anything really, but fires a dropped method on the base class, when I drop an item)

```
public class CustomDragHandler : DefaultDragHandler
{
    public override void Dropped(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        base.Dropped(dropInfo);
    }
}
```

**Custom Drop Handler** (This is where I handle all my data transfer stuff):

```
public class CustomDropHandler : IDropTarget
{
    public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
        dropInfo.DropTargetAdorner = DropTargetAdorners.Highlight;
    }

    public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        // Whole lot of logic in here, fired on drop. 
    }
}
```

Comment: So I could solve my specific case by using events on changes to the target items and creating events for them, however for general purpose the question still remains.

Comment: You should bind the `DragDrop.DropHandler` property to an `IDropTarget` source property of your view model that may return an instance of `CustomDropHandler` for example. What's your issue?